# Customize keyboard shortcuts/hot keys in order to paste different lines of text?

Tags: gratis, open-source, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I would like to find a free/open source program for Windows 7 64-bit that will allow me to make keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc., in order to paste saved lines of text on-the-fly.

This would be extremely useful and efficient for many applications, especially selling on eBay where managing templates doesn't fit my dynamic inventory and selling rules vary greatly from one item to another.

I'd much rather just paste the necessary lines from multiple clipboards using multiple shortcut keys.

Currently, I keep a text file with the various lines which I manually copy/paste when needed.

I understand that making multiple templates is something that could work but it's not something I want to do now.

I also have other uses for custom shortcut keys. Ideally, I could make any shortcut I want if it's not taken by Windows. Combos like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> would be useful and I would simply memorize my new shortcuts. Overriding Windows' shortcuts isn't necessary but if a program allows for that I would consider it a plus too. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

[Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/)

Ditto is a replacement for window's standard clipboard manager and has some pretty powerful features including a copy history and the ability for 10 shortcuts for the previous ten things copied.

[Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ditto-cp/files/Ditto/3.20.54.0/DittoSetup_3_20_54_0.exe/download)

you can start over here http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/Help/DittoGettingStarted.htm